# Substring in tsql using length

Tags: sql, t-sql, substring

Ok, so I am tring to get the first of the last 2 digits of a number. Take for instance 12345601, I want to know if the second to last numeric is a 0. If 0 then I need it to select only the last digit of the int, if different than 0 select the last 2 digits. this is what I have :

```
declare @myint int
set @myint= 12345601
select case when substring(cast (@myint as varchar(50) ) , len(@myint)-1, len(@myint)-1 )     =   0 then right(@myint, 1)
else right(@myint, 2) end
```

Unfortunately, it isn't working and this is where:

```
substring(cast (@myint as varchar(50)), len(@myint)-1, len(@myint)-1 )
```

that substring is coming out at 01, but I need it to come out as 0. Any ideas?

Comment: You can solve this with some divisions and reminders...

Comment: Reminders, that is, about remainders

Comment: substring(expression, start, _length_)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LEFT(RIGHT(@myint,2),1) = 0 THEN RIGHT(@myint,1) ELSE RIGHT(@myint,2) END
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT CAST(RIGHT(@myint,2) as int)
```

If you cast it as an int it should strip the leading zero anyway...

You can see it in action with the code below:

```
declare @myint int
set @myint= 12345601
SELECT CAST(RIGHT(@myint,2) as int)
set @myint= 12345611
SELECT CAST(RIGHT(@myint,2) as int)
```